# Destruct javascript object not setting a default value

Tags: javascript

Im trying to set a default value to an array inside an object but for some reason it keeps the null value. What am i doing wrong and how can i  set the default value  ?

```js
var response = {
  suggestions: null
}

const {
  suggestions = [],
} = response || {}

console.log(suggestions)
```

Comment: Default values only work with `undefined`, not `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default value is only applied if a property is `undefined`, not `null`.

If you want to provide a default value even in case of `null`, you can use nullish operators instead of unpacking.

```
const suggestions = response?.suggestions ?? [];
// defaults to [] if response or response.suggestions is null or undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Default values only work with `undefined`, if you want it to fall through to a default, set your value in your object to `undefined` instead of `null`

```js
var response = {
  suggestions: undefined
}

const {suggestions = [],} = response ||{}
console.log(suggestions)
```